# Completly erasing hard drive

Tags: linux, hard-disk

I've got a laptop which i want to give away to a friend. So i want to completly erase the hard drive that there is nothing on the hard drive, no boot stuff, no nothing - that as soon as he boots up the notebook he gets the message to install something.

I am completly unsure on how to do this .

Maybe a Ubuntu live session from a USB Stick or similar?

Comment: https://dban.org/

Comment: From a Live USB, the easiest way to wipe clean is simply overwrite the entire drive with zeros.  Eg if the HD is `/dev/sdb` the you can `cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdb`.  But you or your friend will need to re-install the operating system after.

Comment: @PhilipCouling That's the point - to make the notebook clean for a new OS.

Comment: @0xSheepdog The link seems [dead](https://downforeveryoneorjustme.com/dban.org).

Comment: The [ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Securely_wipe_disk) has many good options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot from any Live USB distro and then manually overwrite the whole content of the hard disk via `dd` or `cat`. But I believe the easiest way is to use a tool already made for this purpose, like [DBAN](http://www.dban.org/).

From Wikipedia:

> Darik's Boot and Nuke, also known as DBAN (...), is an open-source project hosted on SourceForge. The program is designed to securely erase a hard disk until its data is permanently removed and no longer recoverable, which is achieved by overwriting the data with pseudorandom numbers (...)
>
> DBAN can be booted from a CD, DVD, USB flash drive or diskless using a Preboot Execution Environment. It is based on Linux and supports PATA (IDE), SCSI and SATA hard drives.

Comment: Thank you very much - DBAN was the way to do it!

Answer (score 1):

The simple technique requiring no special tools would be to boot from a Live Linux USB and then overwrite the hard drive.

Assuming the hard drive you want to erase is `/dev/sdb`  You can easily erase with:

```
cat /dev/zero > /dev/sdb
```

This is "good enough" for most cases but could theoretically be recoverable because HDs retain some residual magnetic evidence of their former data.  A more secure version would be

```
cat /dev/urandom > /dev/sdb
```

Or if you're really wearing your [tinfoil hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin_foil_hat) and want to ensure they're not reading your thoughts then do this several times over.

---

Be aware that modern SSDs can only be overwritten so many times.  While this is figure is quite high, you don't commonly overwrite an entire SSD.  If you rewrite the SSD contents too many times it will cripple the drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be safe for sure use `shred`. Not even CIA can undo that ;)