# Why doesn't fdisk -l not show all connected drives?

Tags: ubuntu, fdisk, sata

I've found countless threads started by others where they can't boot from a device because they are using the wrong SATA configuration. Let me assure you this is not my issue.

I work in an IT dept for a company and I have SSDs that I need to wipe. I have created my own Ubuntu machine complete with `dcfldd` and `hdparm` (even though I physically break the HDDs). I have several USB to SATA readers connected to the computer to easily swap connected drives to be wiped.

ALL of the SSDs we wipe were initially imaged in the SATA AHCI configuration. When I run `fdisk -l` in terminal I occasionally run into an SSD that does not get listed.

I've disconnected the drives and tried them in a different SATA reader only to get the same result. The SATA pins on the SSD are not damaged or bent. I've tried using the command `hdparm -I /dev/(drive)` in an attempt to view information of the drive to see if it's locked/frozen/etc but the command fails.

Internet searches yield no results for how to troubleshoot/fix the issue I have or force the connected drive to get wiped despite it not being recognized by the system.

---

I humbly have the two following requests for any data gurus who may stumble upon this issue:

1. I'd love to learn *why* some of the drives are not being recognized and are inaccessible. If it's likely due to a failed drive, is there something I can do to verify this?
2. What are my alternatives for wiping these drives that aren't being recognized? I need to securely clear the company data. Being able to verify the data is destroyed is a plus.

---

**EDIT:**
I don't want to confuse anyone. I follow the US government's protocol and use the command

```
for n in 'seq 7'; do dcfldd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/destination bs=8b conv=notrunc; done
```

to make the data of the drives unrecoverable. Again, the issue is that `/dev/sda` is Ubuntu, and drives `/dev/sdb - /dev/sdf` are the SSDs I am wiping. At times any number of those drives are not listed so the command I use to wipe them does nothing to them. Using commands of this nature are not alternatives to the method I am currently using to wiping the drives.

Also, connecting these drives directly to a SATA cable on the motherboard does not make them recognizable for any live-boot USB.

Comment: Welcome, 1. You can try with an external case. 2. [Completly erasing hard drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522838/completly-erasing-hard-drive).

Comment: Did you check your bios/efi recognizes the drives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fdisk` is a userspace tool, if kernel fails to recognize the device `fdisk` can do nothing about it. After you connect the disk, check `dmesg` or `journalctl`, you should see something similar to

```
kernel: scsi 3:0:0:0: Direct-Access     ATA      Samsung SSD 860  2B6Q PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0
kernel: ata4.00: Enabling discard_zeroes_data
kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] 1953525168 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write Protect is off
kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Mode Sense: 00 3a 00 00
kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Write cache: enabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
kernel:  sda: sda1
kernel: sd 3:0:0:0: [sda] Attached SCSI disk
```

and also `/dev/sdX` node and sysfs directory `/sys/block/sdX` should be created. At this point UDev and tools that use it like `lsblk` should be able to recognize it as a disk and will *try* to work with it (check for partitions/filesystems etc.).

If you see something like

```
kernel: print_req_error: I/O error, dev sda, sector 0
kernel: Buffer I/O error on dev sda, logical block 0, async page read
```

it's usually a good indication that something is wrong with the disk. It doesn't necessary means it is completely broken, it still can be problem with controller or cable and it doesn't mean the data from it cannot be restored. So if you don't have the device node (`/dev/sdX`) and you need to be sure data are "wiped" from it, I guess you'll need to physically destroy the disk to be 100 % sure (but I have no idea what is  the correct government process for that).

You can always try connecting the disk to a different system or using an USB enclosure as @schrodigerscatcuriosity suggested. This could at least eliminate some cable or motherboard SATA controller issues.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give that a try tomorrow and see what I get from the dmesg and journalctl commands.

I have tried it on a different SATA to USB cable, I've tried it on an internal SATA cable, and I've verified the issue isn't the cable.

Comment: I did get those errors with the drives. I'm going to have them shredded to ensure no data will ever be recovered. Thanks for your help.